# How would you solve for this system while it's accelerating?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, weight

So I'm trying to solve for this system with two weights: m1 and m2, with m2 hanging off of m1, which is hanging by two ropes off a ceiling (connected to top of m1) one rope(t1) angled 50 degrees and the other (t2) at 40 degrees. There is one rope between m1 and m2. How do I solve for the tension of the ropes when the whole system is accelerating upwards at 3.5 ms^2? M1 is 8kg and m2 is 9kg.

Answer (score 1):

> How would you solve for this system while it's accelerating?

Just consider the system is at rest and the gravitational acceleration is no longer $g$ but $g+3.5 m/s^2$.